# CommMgr missing from ComponentServices, dcomcnfg

Tags: dcom, windows-server-2022, component-services

A prerequisite of an application I need to install requires some changes to CommMgr but unfortunately it's not appearing in Server 2022 when running either in command prompt to open Component Services..

`dcomcnfg` or `mmc comexp.msc /32 command`

Is there a fix for this or has CommMgr been removed from Component Services?

[image: CommMgr Missing]